# NSURLConnection sends data twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, upload, nsurlconnection

I'm uploading image to my server and while I'm uploading image I'm trying to show user a progress bar of the upload. But in a NSURLConnection delegate method `connection:
   didSendBodyData: totalBytesWritten: totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` I get confusing numbers. Lets say my data is X bytes long. At first I get totalBytesExpectedToWrite to be X, but then after totalBytesWritten reaches totalBytesExpectedToWrite my connection still progresses with upload and totalBytesExpectedToWrite shift to 2X. It's always exactly 2X and I don't know why. Connection is the same (by id) and I invoke it only once.

Here is my code for uploading image:

```
- (void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)image
{ 
// random boundary string
NSString *boundary = @"----8745633765875256----";

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSMutableData *requestData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

// append boundary and separate it with new line
[requestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting up header files, appending image and separating body with boundary
[requestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ad_image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"tmp.jpg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requestData appendData:imageData];
[requestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  

// initializing request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&user_id=%@&api_key=%@", kUrlImageTempAdd, userID, apiKey]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// setting up content-type "form" to multipart/form-data for image upload
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];

//setting up content length
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-

// connection init and start
NSURLConnection *connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:true] autorelease];
}
```

and here is my delegate method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
NSLog(@"connection %@ bytes sent %d/%d (%f%%)", connection, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, ((float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100.0f);
}
```

Any suggestions why this is happening? I'm losing my mind over here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `-connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` says

> The value of totalBytesExpectedToWrite may change during the upload if
>   the request needs to be retransmitted due to a lost connection or an
>   authentication challenge from the server.

(The documentation for the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods seems to have been largely lost when it transitioned from being an informal to a formal protocol. You can check the comments in the header or have Xcode download one of the older docsets and check there.)

You can implement some of the other delegate methods to observe what might be happening, like an authentication challenge.

Comment: Not sure if I should answer my own question or mark this one as answer. But this is what happened. I was uploading images to server that was password protected. Because of that upload needed to be done twice (dunno exactly why). As soon as me removed pass-protection it started to work fine!

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method you are using can be called a lot of times, as it reports status updates on the data upload to the server...

The NSURLConnection object will transfer the data to the server in packet of bytes and each time a packet is sent it will call the delegate method.

If you only want to know when the upload did end you need to use this delegate method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

[See more in the official documentation of the NSURLDownloadDelegate delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLDownloadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLDownloadDelegate)

Comment: OK, but how can I update my progress bar then? Any this doesn't really explain why is it always 2X. Doesn't matter how small or big image (file) I user?!

Comment: Well, then you need to use the delegate you are using. But even if it's called multiple times the totalBytesWritten should be the one that you should use to update your progress bar

Comment: It should be called multiple times because data is sent in chunks, but thing that is weird to me is that (in a same connection) totalBytesExpectedToWrite changes. As if size of package changed. I'll check if server is maybe requesting resend base on @Ken Thomases feedback (because of the authentication challenge)